# Why ethers.js sign function not working?

Tags: ether, javascript, web3-providers, ethers.js

I am using the ethers.js library, and am trying to code a transaction. Here is a snippet where I connect a wallet to a provider, connect to a contract I want to call a function in, and try to call the `transfer` function in the target contract, using the promise generated to sign the transaction with my wallet:

```
let mywallet =wallet.connect(providers)
let contract=new ethers.Contract(contractadd,abi,mywallet)
contract.functions.transfer(address2,amount).then(function(tx){
let signpromise=mywallet.sign(tx)
});
```

When I try to execute this, I get the following error:

```
invalid object key v
```

Why isn't the sign function working? Thanks.

Comment: i use web3js and not ether.js but probably you should sign the tx before sending it and not after :/

Comment: Which provider are you using? Does it support signing transactions?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to signal this, but I believe this question is now clear enough to be reopened.